# Why does the skin not work to button when using 5.5 plugin?

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am using Kony 5.5 plugin then took build for BBQ10. I declared red colour for the button in the skin.  But the colour has not applied to the button means black colour button displayed instead of red colour button in the Q 10 device. I want to change the colour of the button. Please give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:
1. make sure that under the Skins for the button widget, there is not a forked setting for BB; you may have changed the "Common" skin, but if there is a declared skin specifically for BB, then it will override your settings.
2. Try adding a new button just to test, specifically set the color to red, and see if that button is displaying properly.  This will show if there is an overall issue or just an issue with the button you are trying to configure ( this is more of a sanity check than a technical fix )

Answer (score 0):

Customized skin using colour doesn't work to Blackberry 10 devices.It is a limitation of Kony platform.Please read documents the following link.

[Docs](http://docs.kony.com/konyonpremises/#welcome_studio.htm?TocPath=Kony%20Development%20Cloud%7C_____0)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check whether you choose skin option for button then check its under common. Because you may choose on Windows, iOS or other. Try this:

```
//Defining the properties for a button with skin: "btnSkin".
var btnBasic = {
        id:"button1", isVisible:true, skin:"btnSkin", 
        focusSkin:"btnFSkin", text:"Click Here"
};
var btnLayout = {
        containerWeight:100, padding:[5,5,5,5], 
        margin:[5,5,5,5], hExpand:true, vExpand:false,
        displayText:true
};
var btnPSP={};

//Creating the button.

var button1 = new kony.ui.Button(btnBasic, btnLayout, btnPSP);

//Reading skin of the button.

alert("Button skin ::"+button1.skin);
```

Comment: Please use proper english while posting messages. This isn't a text messaging website or app.